# How to change wlan0's channel

Tags: command-line, wireless, networking, configuration, ifconfig

When setting the channel to wlan0, I get an error:

```
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Device or resource busy.
```

I tried to shutdown wlan0 by:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
```

and wlan0 did not appear in the ifconfig result, but I still get the error when I use this command to switch channels:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 channal 1
```

The funniest thing is I just used this method to change channal from 4 to 6, and now I want to change the channal from 6 to 1, but I can't finish it. Did I miss something?

Comment: I think that the main problem is that you are typing "channal", instead of *channel*.

Answer (score 2):

Change command from

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 channal 1
```

to

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel 1
```